# Размещение виджета ленты сообщества Facebook по ширине блока

Tags: css, iframe, facebook, facebook-widgets

При размещении виджета ленты сообщества на сайте, он (виджет) имеет фиксированную ширину. Мне нужно, чтобы он занимал всю ширину блока.
Вставляю с помощью iframe:

```
<div>
  <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FLandmarkGuestHouseMoscow%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=true&show_facepile=true&appId" width="640" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
</div>
```

Пробовала менять width на auto, на 100%. Попробовала в файле css менять width, в том числе, с использованием !important. Ширина остается фиксированной.

В настройках при копировании виджета указала пункт "Адаптировать под ширину контейнера плагина".

Как можно его растянуть по ширине?

[Описание плагина в документации facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена использованием js, а не iframe и прописыванием в стилях:

```
.fb-page, .fb-page iframe[style], .fb-page span {
    width: 100% !important;
}
.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style], .fb-comments span {
   width: 100% !important;
}
```